# Number of instances in training images MaskRCNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, mask, object-detection-api, faster-rcnn

I want to train a MaskRCNN model using the Object detection API Tensorflow.

I'm currently annotating the images using the  [Pixel Annotation Tool](https://github.com/abreheret/PixelAnnotationTool).

My question is: Should I create a training data set with ONE segmented feature per image, or can I annotate several features (of the same class) in a sigle image?

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty old question, but I got here thorough Google so why not.

To train Mask-RCNN, you need to create a separate binary mask for each instance. Many image segmentation tools do that automatically. I personally used LabelBox in my most recent project, but there are many open source, free software as well. [Here is a list](https://lionbridge.ai/articles/image-annotation-tools-for-computer-vision/) I found on Google, but I cannot really recommend anything specific.